# How to get all elements on the viewport using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `:visible` jQuery selector says that it will select all the elements which consumes space. Is there any other selector that will get the visible elements on the viewport ?

Comment: What's your aversion to using `:visible`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I think the OP wants only visible elements that are in the viewport, where `:visible` will select any element with a width and height.

Comment: The doc also states that "Elements with visibiliy:hidden" are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout. But i want to get only the elements that are "visible and currently on viewport" not just visible.

Comment: @j08691 ah. must have overlooked that bit at the end!

Comment: Loop through the results of :visible and filter out the ones with visibility hidden and opacity zero as well as above the scroll?

Comment: That is not very efficent, Since in my case the document contains more than 1000 elements (special use case) and it is not very efficent to loop through every time. This one is really awesome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782925/using-jquery-how-do-you-find-only-visible-elements-and-leave-hidden-elements-al

Comment: for what it's worth I think this is a great question, and I don't agree that the referred answer has the solution to this problem. This question is about requesting all visible elements in the viewport. The other question is about checking whether a given element is inside the viewport or not.