# How do I select only my list items that aren't hidden using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

A really simple question I'm sure but...

I have an unordered list, in which some amount of the list items have been slid up. I want to extract information from spans within the visible list items only, using an $.each loop.

I want to write something along these lines to access this information but I don't know what the right parameter is:

```
$("li.class").each(function(){
  if ("li.class" *isn't hidden*) { 
    // get information from span
  }
})
```

The best I can come up with is adding a class each time a list item is slid up and then removing that class when it slides back down, which I guess would be fine, but I'm suspecting jQuery already has something in place.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery

Comment: There seems to be a working answer over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16782950/5563779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    $(function() {
        $('li.class:visible').each(function() {

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:visible` pseudo selector:

```
$("li.class:visible").each(function() {
    // get information from span, like ...
    $("span", this).text();
})
```

Comment: Makes sense (and is probably something I should have known!) Thanks!