# How to select only the fields without Display: none CSS property using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to select only the fields who's CSS property is not Display: "None".
Please have a look at the code and please let me know what an I doing wrong?

function (controlId) {
            var returnValidFlag = true;

```
        //var requiredClass = $this.find('.required');
        //console.log(requiredClass);

        $('.required:not([display=none])').each(function () {
            // Get 'this' HTML object's ID
            var thisInputID = $(this).attr('id');

            // Get 'this' error message 
            var thisErrorMessageID = thisInputID + 'ErrorMessage';
            // console.log('Error ID: ' + thisErrorMessageID);

            // Get the user input value
            var thisInputValue = $(this).val();
            console.log('Input ID: ' + thisInputValue + " " + thisErrorMessageID);

            if (thisInputValue =='') {
                returnValidFlag = false;
                $('#' + thisErrorMessageID).show();
            } else {
                returnValidFlag = true;
                $('#' + thisErrorMessageID).hide();
            }
        });

        return returnValidFlag;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery, how do you find only visible elements and leave hidden elements alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782925/using-jquery-how-do-you-find-only-visible-elements-and-leave-hidden-elements-al)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

`display` is not part of an element's attributes , it is a style property

```
$('.required:visible)').each(...
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use *filter*.

```
$('div').filter((index, node) => $(node).css('display') !== 'none')
```