# How to get values of display none fields in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 10 input type(text) each have one unique id  in a form  I have set them as display none by default .Each input type is shown one buy one
after clicking a common button

```
$(button).click( function(){

var id =this.id;

$('#'+id).show();


});
```

User may select any number of fields from 1-10.  When form is submitted i want values of only those field which are shown . **I am using ajax to send this data .**
I tried use **queryselectorAll**  using class name   but it is giving me all 10 values ( empty values for hidden input).

How do i get only shown input field values

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782925/using-jquery-how-do-you-find-only-visible-elements-and-leave-hidden-elements-al/16782950)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a [`:visible` psuedoclass](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) that you can use:

```
const $visible_inputs = $("form#form_id input:visible")
$visible_inputs.each( (index, element) => {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```